# Moving Gradient Bar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a colored bar, with another color moving trough this bar. It should look like this, with the white part moving:

[image: Example bar]

I was thinking about something with gradient and the anmiation property of CSS 3. **I don't** want to use JS!
I tried something like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar_line"></div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar_line {
animation: gradient 5s linear infinite; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes gradient
{

0% {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #DDFFDD 2%, #BBFFBB 4%, #AAFFAA 5%, #99FF99 6%, #88FF88 7%, #77FF77 8%, #66EF66 9%, #55DF55 10%, #44CE44 11%, #33BD33 12%, #22AC22 13%, #119B11 14%, #008A00 15%, #008A00 86%, #119B11 87%, #22AC22 88%, #33BD33 89%, #44CE44 90%, #55DF55 91%, #66EF66 92%, #77FF77 93%, #88FF88 94%, #99FF99 95%, #AAFFAA 96%, #BBFFBB 97%, #CCFFCC 98%, #DDFFDD 99%, #EEFFEE 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #DDFFDD 2%, #BBFFBB 4%, #AAFFAA 5%, #99FF99 6%, #88FF88 7%, #77FF77 8%, #66EF66 9%, #55DF55 10%, #44CE44 11%, #33BD33 12%, #22AC22 13%, #119B11 14%, #008A00 15%, #008A00 86%, #119B11 87%, #22AC22 88%, #33BD33 89%, #44CE44 90%, #55DF55 91%, #66EF66 92%, #77FF77 93%, #88FF88 94%, #99FF99 95%, #AAFFAA 96%, #BBFFBB 97%, #CCFFCC 98%, #DDFFDD 99%, #EEFFEE 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #DDFFDD 2%, #BBFFBB 4%, #AAFFAA 5%, #99FF99 6%, #88FF88 7%, #77FF77 8%, #66EF66 9%, #55DF55 10%, #44CE44 11%, #33BD33 12%, #22AC22 13%, #119B11 14%, #008A00 15%, #008A00 86%, #119B11 87%, #22AC22 88%, #33BD33 89%, #44CE44 90%, #55DF55 91%, #66EF66 92%, #77FF77 93%, #88FF88 94%, #99FF99 95%, #AAFFAA 96%, #BBFFBB 97%, #CCFFCC 98%, #DDFFDD 99%, #EEFFEE 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #DDFFDD 2%, #BBFFBB 4%, #AAFFAA 5%, #99FF99 6%, #88FF88 7%, #77FF77 8%, #66EF66 9%, #55DF55 10%, #44CE44 11%, #33BD33 12%, #22AC22 13%, #119B11 14%, #008A00 15%, #008A00 86%, #119B11 87%, #22AC22 88%, #33BD33 89%, #44CE44 90%, #55DF55 91%, #66EF66 92%, #77FF77 93%, #88FF88 94%, #99FF99 95%, #AAFFAA 96%, #BBFFBB 97%, #CCFFCC 98%, #DDFFDD 99%, #EEFFEE 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #DDFFDD 2%, #BBFFBB 4%, #AAFFAA 5%, #99FF99 6%, #88FF88 7%, #77FF77 8%, #66EF66 9%, #55DF55 10%, #44CE44 11%, #33BD33 12%, #22AC22 13%, #119B11 14%, #008A00 15%, #008A00 86%, #119B11 87%, #22AC22 88%, #33BD33 89%, #44CE44 90%, #55DF55 91%, #66EF66 92%, #77FF77 93%, #88FF88 94%, #99FF99 95%, #AAFFAA 96%, #BBFFBB 97%, #CCFFCC 98%, #DDFFDD 99%, #EEFFEE 100%); /* W3C */
}

1% {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #EEFFEE 0%, #FFFFFF 1%, #EEFFEE 2%, #DDFFDD 3%, #BBFFBB 5%, #AAFFAA 6%, #99FF99 7%, #88FF88 8%, #77FF77 9%, #66EF66 10%, #55DF55 11%, #44CE44 12%, #33BD33 13%, #22AC22 14%, #119B11 15%, #008A00 16%, #008A00 87%, #119B11 88%, #22AC22 89%, #33BD33 90%, #44CE44 91%, #55DF55 92%, #66EF66 93%, #77FF77 94%, #88FF88 95%, #99FF99 96%, #AAFFAA 97%, #BBFFBB 98%, #CCFFCC 99%, #DDFFDD 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(, #EEFFEE 0%, #FFFFFF 1%, #EEFFEE 2%, #DDFFDD 3%, #BBFFBB 5%, #AAFFAA 6%, #99FF99 7%, #88FF88 8%, #77FF77 9%, #66EF66 10%, #55DF55 11%, #44CE44 12%, #33BD33 13%, #22AC22 14%, #119B11 15%, #008A00 16%, #008A00 87%, #119B11 88%, #22AC22 89%, #33BD33 90%, #44CE44 91%, #55DF55 92%, #66EF66 93%, #77FF77 94%, #88FF88 95%, #99FF99 96%, #AAFFAA 97%, #BBFFBB 98%, #CCFFCC 99%, #DDFFDD 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #EEFFEE 0%, #FFFFFF 1%, #EEFFEE 2%, #DDFFDD 3%, #BBFFBB 5%, #AAFFAA 6%, #99FF99 7%, #88FF88 8%, #77FF77 9%, #66EF66 10%, #55DF55 11%, #44CE44 12%, #33BD33 13%, #22AC22 14%, #119B11 15%, #008A00 16%, #008A00 87%, #119B11 88%, #22AC22 89%, #33BD33 90%, #44CE44 91%, #55DF55 92%, #66EF66 93%, #77FF77 94%, #88FF88 95%, #99FF99 96%, #AAFFAA 97%, #BBFFBB 98%, #CCFFCC 99%, #DDFFDD 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #EEFFEE 0%, #FFFFFF 1%, #EEFFEE 2%, #DDFFDD 3%, #BBFFBB 5%, #AAFFAA 6%, #99FF99 7%, #88FF88 8%, #77FF77 9%, #66EF66 10%, #55DF55 11%, #44CE44 12%, #33BD33 13%, #22AC22 14%, #119B11 15%, #008A00 16%, #008A00 87%, #119B11 88%, #22AC22 89%, #33BD33 90%, #44CE44 91%, #55DF55 92%, #66EF66 93%, #77FF77 94%, #88FF88 95%, #99FF99 96%, #AAFFAA 97%, #BBFFBB 98%, #CCFFCC 99%, #DDFFDD 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #EEFFEE 0%, #FFFFFF 1%, #EEFFEE 2%, #DDFFDD 3%, #BBFFBB 5%, #AAFFAA 6%, #99FF99 7%, #88FF88 8%, #77FF77 9%, #66EF66 10%, #55DF55 11%, #44CE44 12%, #33BD33 13%, #22AC22 14%, #119B11 15%, #008A00 16%, #008A00 87%, #119B11 88%, #22AC22 89%, #33BD33 90%, #44CE44 91%, #55DF55 92%, #66EF66 93%, #77FF77 94%, #88FF88 95%, #99FF99 96%, #AAFFAA 97%, #BBFFBB 98%, #CCFFCC 99%, #DDFFDD 100%); /* W3C */
}

2% {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #DDFFDD 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #FFFFFF 2%, #EEFFEE 3%, #DDFFDD 4%, #BBFFBB 6%, #AAFFAA 7%, #99FF99 8%, #88FF88 9%, #77FF77 10%, #66EF66 11%, #55DF55 12%, #44CE44 13%, #33BD33 14%, #22AC22 15%, #119B11 16%, #008A00 17%, #008A00 88%, #119B11 89%, #22AC22 90%, #33BD33 91%, #44CE44 92%, #55DF55 93%, #66EF66 94%, #77FF77 95%, #88FF88 96%, #99FF99 97%, #AAFFAA 98%, #BBFFBB 99%, #CCFFCC 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(, #DDFFDD 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #FFFFFF 2%, #EEFFEE 3%, #DDFFDD 4%, #BBFFBB 6%, #AAFFAA 7%, #99FF99 8%, #88FF88 9%, #77FF77 10%, #66EF66 11%, #55DF55 12%, #44CE44 13%, #33BD33 14%, #22AC22 15%, #119B11 16%, #008A00 17%, #008A00 88%, #119B11 89%, #22AC22 90%, #33BD33 91%, #44CE44 92%, #55DF55 93%, #66EF66 94%, #77FF77 95%, #88FF88 96%, #99FF99 97%, #AAFFAA 98%, #BBFFBB 99%, #CCFFCC 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #DDFFDD 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #FFFFFF 2%, #EEFFEE 3%, #DDFFDD 4%, #BBFFBB 6%, #AAFFAA 7%, #99FF99 8%, #88FF88 9%, #77FF77 10%, #66EF66 11%, #55DF55 12%, #44CE44 13%, #33BD33 14%, #22AC22 15%, #119B11 16%, #008A00 17%, #008A00 88%, #119B11 89%, #22AC22 90%, #33BD33 91%, #44CE44 92%, #55DF55 93%, #66EF66 94%, #77FF77 95%, #88FF88 96%, #99FF99 97%, #AAFFAA 98%, #BBFFBB 99%, #CCFFCC 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #DDFFDD 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #FFFFFF 2%, #EEFFEE 3%, #DDFFDD 4%, #BBFFBB 6%, #AAFFAA 7%, #99FF99 8%, #88FF88 9%, #77FF77 10%, #66EF66 11%, #55DF55 12%, #44CE44 13%, #33BD33 14%, #22AC22 15%, #119B11 16%, #008A00 17%, #008A00 88%, #119B11 89%, #22AC22 90%, #33BD33 91%, #44CE44 92%, #55DF55 93%, #66EF66 94%, #77FF77 95%, #88FF88 96%, #99FF99 97%, #AAFFAA 98%, #BBFFBB 99%, #CCFFCC 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #DDFFDD 0%, #EEFFEE 1%, #FFFFFF 2%, #EEFFEE 3%, #DDFFDD 4%, #BBFFBB 6%, #AAFFAA 7%, #99FF99 8%, #88FF88 9%, #77FF77 10%, #66EF66 11%, #55DF55 12%, #44CE44 13%, #33BD33 14%, #22AC22 15%, #119B11 16%, #008A00 17%, #008A00 88%, #119B11 89%, #22AC22 90%, #33BD33 91%, #44CE44 92%, #55DF55 93%, #66EF66 94%, #77FF77 95%, #88FF88 96%, #99FF99 97%, #AAFFAA 98%, #BBFFBB 99%, #CCFFCC 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

to be continued...

Believe it or not, it works! I wrote a script which generated those lines. But it's huge, bigger than a picture, therefore not useable.

I hope you'll find better ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html part is quiet easy, all you need is two different divs.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="movement"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.movement 
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 25%, white 50%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%); 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 25%, white 50%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 25%, white 50%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 25%, white 50%, rgba(0,255,0,0.7) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%); 
    width: 400px; 
    height: 5px; 
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: gradient 6s linear infinite;
    animation: gradient 6s linear infinite;
}
.background 
{
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #070;
}
@-webkit-keyframes gradient
{
    0%   {left: -400px;}
    100% {left: 1000px;}
}
@keyframes gradient 
{
    0%   {left: -400px;}
    100% {left: 1000px;}
}
```

The background div is obviously for the background, size, color that's it.

The second div is the gradient div with your second color. It is colored with a gradient.
The animation causes the div to move over the background.

That's it! Try out here: http://jsfiddle.net/fgeLnbkm/2/

If you want to customize it, it's quiet handy, most of the things are easy to change, except from the gradient of the movement div.

Comment: This is awesome. Nice job!

Comment: Even better: use pseudo-elements to avoid [divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/fgeLnbkm/3/

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of linear-gradient you can use radial-gradient, in this case you will need just 5 color stops but not hundred.
2. Instead of hundred keyframes you need just three of them: 0% 50% and 100% (or even just 2). All intermediate values will be interpolated.