# Animating linear-gradient to create a loading bar

Tags: css

I want to build a loading bar, with one coloured element going a long a grey bar.

I am fairly bad at CSS, so I have some trouble with animating gradients. 
My current approach is based on this answer: [Make some gradient move endlessly in a progress bar like in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305596/make-some-gradient-move-endlessly-in-a-progress-bar-like-in-windows-7)

```
foo {
  background-color: $cGray300;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  $cGray300 0%, $cGray300 30%, #fed0d0 30%, #fed0d0 40%, $cGray300 40%, $cGray300 100%) repeat;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  animation-name: moving-gradient;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moving-gradient {
  0% { background-position: left bottom; }
  100% { background-position: right bottom; }
}
```

This is the result:
[image: current progress]

Though I want one, red bigger element that reappears on the left when it disappears on the right.

Comment: Use JS/JQ. When the "red element" (let's give it a class 'red') touches the right end then move it to left 0 (or the left of the wrapper). Then move it back to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a gradient for this, just a pseudo-element, positioning & a transform.

```css
.bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 2em auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
  animation: progress 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This Code is Based on @Paulie_D answer and 
i make it responsive for any sizes and little more changes

to become like material preloader

```css
.state-changed{
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:20px;
border:1px solid silver;
}

.state-changed::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        height: 2px; 
        background: red;
        animation: progress 1.5s infinite ease-in-out ;
    }
    
    @keyframes progress {
    0% {
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
    50% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        right: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="state-changed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [pen](http://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/yJzmjq)

Using just CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="loader8"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left:-120px;
    }
    to {
        left:100%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left:-120px;
    }
    to {
        left:100%;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left:-120px;
    }
    to {
        left:100%;
    }
}
@keyframes greenglow {
    from {
        left:-120px;
    }
    to {
        left:100%;
    }
}

.loader8 {
    width:250px;
    height:16px;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius:0px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #E6E6E6;
    margin:5px;
}

.loader8:after {
    content: " ";
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    top:-50%;
    height:250%;
    position:absolute;
    animation: greenglow 3s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: greenglow 3s linear infinite;
    z-index:2;
    background: #1CAE30;
}
```